# Doing basic math in regex capture groups

Tags: json, regex, powershell

I have "a few" (hundred) json files in a directory, which contain a fair amount of differently typed json objects in arbitrary tree structures. Many (but not all) of the objects have an absolute canvas position like the following:

```
"position":{"x":880.8230590820313,"y":437.6084899902344,"z":0.0}
```

Now I want to loop through all these files and increase the "y" position in all objects by a fixed amount, say 24.

To make my life easy and to not have to traverse through a tree structure, I thought to use powershell regexp like this:

```
$content = Get-Content -path "SimpleSample.json" // TODO: Loop through directory
$content -Replace '"position":\{"x":([\d.]*),"y":(\d*).', '"position":\{"x":$1,"y":($2+24).' | Out-File -Encoding "UTF8" "SimpleSampleOut.json"
```

and the result even is "nearly" what I want:

```
"position":\{"x":880.8230590820313,"y":(437+24).6084899902344,"z":0.0}
```

Of course to get valid JSON, I need the calculation result, not the calculation, in the resulting file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need a callback function for that kind of replacement. Otherweise [convert](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/10/08/use-powershell-to-convert-to-or-from-json/) the JSON string so you can operate on the actual values.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Seems I don't know how to do it correctly. I am so far at `[Regex]::Replace($content, '"position":\{"x":([\d.]*),"y":(\d*).', {return ("`"position`":{`"x`":" + $args[1] + ",`"y`":" + ($args[2]+24) + ".");})`, but the numbers in $1 and $2 seem to be zeros.

Comment: Please take another look at my answer to the other question. You need the `Replace()` *object* method, not the (static) `Replace()` *class* method. `$re = [regex]'"position":\{"x":([\d.]*),"y":(\d*).'; $re.Replace($content, {...})`. And the arguments to the scriptblock (PowerShell's version of anonymous functions) are the match objects. The values of the captured groups can be accessed via `$args[0].Groups[<index>].Value`.